# Why interface definition in f2py raises "Syntax Error" and "Unexpected data declaration statement in INTERFACE block" errors?

Tags: fortran, f2py

I try to define two functions to be consumed in Numpy using f2py. One function also calls the other.

Therefore I prepare the following source code and define an explicit interface so the compiler knows about the called function:

```
subroutine get_value(ts, c_open)

        implicit none

        integer(kind=4), intent(in)                :: ts(:)                
        integer(kind=4), intent(out)               :: c_open               

        ! SIMULATED CALCULATION
        c_open = ts(1)
        
end subroutine

subroutine get_value_range(ts, a, b, ca_open)

        implicit none

        ! INTERFACE TO get_value
        interface
                subroutine get_value (ts, c_open)
                        integer(kind=4), intent(in)                :: ts(:)                
                        integer(kind=4), intent(out)               :: c_open
                end subroutine get_value
        end interface       
        
        integer(kind=4), intent(in)                :: ts(:)
        integer(kind=4), intent(in)                :: a
        integer(kind=4), intent(in)                :: b         
        integer(kind=4), intent(out)               :: ca_open(b-a)

        ! INDIVIDUAL RETURN VALUES
        integer(kind=4)                            :: c1_open

        ! AUXILIARY VARIABLES
        integer                                    :: i                    ! ITERATOR
        
        ! FILL IN OUTPUT ARRAY
        do i = 1,10
                call get_value(ts, c1_open)
                ca_open(i) = c1_open
        end do
                

end subroutine
```

These are the errors after trying to compile it with `f2py`:

```
   86 |               subroutine get_value(ts,c_open) 
      |                                              1
Error: Syntax error in SUBROUTINE statement at (1)

   88 |                   integer(kind=4), intent(in),dimension(:) :: ts
      |                                                                        1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement in INTERFACE block at (1)

   89 |                   integer(kind=4), intent(out) :: c_open
      |                                                                        1
Error: Unexpected data declaration statement in INTERFACE block at (1)

   90 |               end subroutine get_value
      |                 1
Error: Expecting END INTERFACE statement at (1)
```

I am compiling it with:

```
f2py -c -m mylib myfile.f90
```

to get a shared object I can import in Python. I am using `gfortran9`.

Comment: Is the fragment you show the entire file? From the error messages there are things before the lines you show (line 86?) and they could be important for context (where a subroutine declaration may exist, for example).

Comment: Yes it is, you are seeing line 86 because I also have the same file embedded into a larger library (6 source fortran files with proprietary data). For the SO question I have narrowed the scope to the minimum reproducible example. 

If you try to compile just the excerpt of code included in this question, you get those errors. 

I have managed to get it working removing the `interface` description and encapsulating everything inside a `module`. It forces you to use `library.module.function` instead of `library.function` in Python but it works fine.

Comment: I don't know python or f2py at all, but there are a number of questions on SO where f2py seems to get confused over interface blocks, it might be worth sticking "interface fortran f2py" in a search engine and seeing what comes up. But modules are the proper Fortran way to do it, so I'm pleased that works - my suspicion (but I don't know) is that the problem is because f2py doesn't understand all of modern Fortran.

Comment: @M.E. If you try "f2py -m mylib myfile.f90" (<-- no "-c"), I think you will get a temporary source file (like mylib-xxxx.f) that f2py creates as a wrapper. It seems f2py tries to create a F77 wrapper when the routines are placed at the "top-level" (i.e. not within a module), and the generated F77 wrapper has nested interface blocks, which seems to cause the above error... So I also think inserting the routines into a module would be more straightforward.

Comment: Also, on the python side, you can first make an alias like "fmod = library.module", and then "y = fmod.function(x)" later (so no need to type "library"). Also "myfunc = library.module.function" and "y = myfunc(x)" etc also works, so there are several short-cuts (?) for typing

Comment: I finally did `from mylib import mymodule as lmymodule` so I just type `lmymodule.myfunction` in Python. It is good enough, and as Ian is saying, that is the "proper" Fortran way of implementing this.